# How to publish web service of ASP.NET Core to IIS

Tags: web-services, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

According to this article:
https://fullstackmark.com/post/3/websockets-with-aspnet-core-and-xamarin-forms

I created a ASP.NET Core project and now i want a web service that run this project so i can accees to this site by this url:
http://localhost:51276/

What i have now?
I can access to this url and see the site only if i clicked with right button on this file: Views/Home/Index.cshtml and click on 'View in browser'

But if i close my visual studio and try to enter this address directly in the browser - NOT WORKING!

I need this run on webservice because it is a chat api (sockets).

THANK YOU!

Comment: so you want to host it in local system right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this link for hosting asp.net core application in IIS  [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis)

You can always host your application in IIS express in localhost for development purpose.
Open cmd and navigate to

```
cd C:\programfiles\iisexpress
```

then run

```
iisexperss.exe /path:"path to your published folder" /port:51276
```

Check the accepted parameters of iisexpress.exe in the help to pass, port no and additional information for hosting the site

Comment: I need it for finish my project - not only for development.
I want to access to the site via http://localhost:51276/
You see the article that i was attached?

Comment: i think you need to learn a lot about webhosting! only in local system you can use localhost:portno! if you want to host it means, you need to buy a domain and hosting that supports .net core and publish.

Comment: The link that you attached is the solution. Just need to install  .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle

Comment: I know it - dont worry. localhost is jsut for the question - of course i have a domain name